# Binding a datatable to a aspxgridview combobox column

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a ASPxGridView with a combobox column. Now i want to bind a datatable to that combobox, this datatable is made in the code behind so it does not exist at the moment the gridview is being made. instead i have to bind the datatable to the combobox in the HtmlEditFormCreated event.
I tried :

```
ASPxGridView4.FindControl("PNaam");
```

But that does not seem to allow me to bind the datatable to it. So i was wondering how can i bind the datatable to the combobox column inside the HtmlEditFormCreated event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the Page_Init event as shown below to bind the column's editor to your DataTable:

```
(ASPxGridView1.Columns["SomeFieldName"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn).PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = yourDataTable;
```